# merge contacts with different currency values

Tags: contact, merge, multi-currency

I've got two contacts that I can't merge and here is the message I receive from Salesforce

> The selected records have different currency types. To merge them,
> first edit their currency types to be the same.

Thanks for your help on this

Comment: By the message it says that currency is different, so I assume the org has multi-currency, so you will have to change the data before merging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8O6tSAF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, unfortunately. You'll have to edit the contacts to have matching currency on the Contact Currency field (`CurrencyIsoCode`) before merging.

You can upvote the idea for [Dupe Merging Improvements](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdX4UUAV/dupe-merging-improvements) which calls out this limitation.